# Adding dynamic parameter value to visual title in quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to configure the title of a visual to display the selected value of a Parameter?
Let's say I have a parameter + control "Day" and it is set to 10. Now I want the title of my visual to say "This visual at day 10". Now suppose I change the value of the parameter in the controls menu to 15, the visual title should display the sentence "This visual at day 15" automatically. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you should take a second look at the answers below, since the answer for your question has changed. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible (as of now May 2021) to use parameters in the titles of your charts.

You can simply type '<<$ParamterName>>' into the chart title box or title and it will insert the value of the parameter.

There is also an option in the little context menus in the tool itself to add it to the title you are typing

[image: Detail about where to find the context menu and how to write the parameter so it gets replaced when shown]

ps. don't forget the '$'

Answer (score 2):

A parameter can be can be used in a sheet title, but not a visual title. Perhaps you could put your desired title as a sheet title.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I needed the visual title to be dynamic. Anyway, thanks a lot.